# Rendering HTML5 template in web-component slot from different file

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, html5-template

I'm just getting started with web-components and trying to abstract repeating HTML code to their own files, so not like I'm doing with `<nav-bar>` and `<bootstrap-wrapper>`, but more of a component based approach.

Now, I want to structure my project in such a way that my `template` is sent to a `slot` in `index.html` to render.

How I can render `welcome.html` inside of my `index.html`, also, how do I then navigate from `welcome.html` to another template

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <bootstrap-wrapper>
        <nav-bar></nav-bar>
        <span slot="content"></span>
    </bootstrap-wrapper>
</body>

<script src="actio.js"></script>

</html>
```

**actio.js**

```js
customElements.define(
  'nav-bar',
  class NavBar extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `
        <nav class="nav">
          <a class="nav-link" href="welcome.html">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="enter-names.html">Enter Names</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="calculator.html">Calculator</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="history.html">History</a>
        </nav>
      `;
    }
  }
);

const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
          <div class="jumbotron bg-dark text-white">
            <p><slot name="content" /></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
`;

customElements.define(
  'bootstrap-wrapper',
  class BootstrapWrapper extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.attachShadow({
        mode: 'open'
      }).appendChild(
        template.content.cloneNode(true)
      );
    }
  }
);
```

**welcome.html**

```html
<template class="welcome">
    <h1>Household Budget Calculator</h1>
    <h3>No more arguments about how to divide your household expenses!</h3>
    <h4>How it works:</h4>
    <ol>
        <li>Enter names</li>
        <li>Fill household expenses</li>
        <li>Each of you fills in their income</li>
        <li>Hit Calculate</li>
        <li>Enjoy a blissful partnership!</li>
    </ol>

    <button onclick="location.href='enter-names.html'"
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary">Enter Names</button>
</template>
```

Comment: Maybe try https://github.com/justinfagnani/html-include-element

Comment: @BennyPowers ideally I want to avoid installing anything and do the whole thing without Node.

Comment: use fetch() to import external html files

Comment: +1 use fetch; If you use VSCode/Live Server instead of ``.html`` extension use ``.xml`` because LiveServer injects extra content in html files. Do look at the mentioned ``html-include`` source code for inspiration... it does use fetch.

Comment: @FlorestanKorp no node here?
```
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/html-include-element?module"></script>
<html-include src="some-partial.html"></html-include>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `fetch()`, which is an asynchronous function.

In your `BoostrapWrapper` class, add a method:

```
async function loadTemplate( filename ) {
    var response = await fetch( filename )
    var text = await response.text()
    this.querySelector( span[slot=content]' ).innerHTML = text
}
```

No need to include the code in a `<template>` element unless you use Javascript code inside. In this latter case you'll need to create a temporary `<template>` element.

You can then call the method with any HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fetch()` I implemented a method called `createComponent()` that takes a path and fetches an `HTML` file, which contains a `<template>` and appends it to `#app-root` in my `index.html`

**main.js**

```js
function createComponent(path) { // path is relative to root of project

  fetch(path)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function (html) {
      const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
      const template = doc.querySelector('head > template');

      document.querySelector('#app-root').innerHTML = '';
      document.querySelector('#app-root').appendChild(template.content);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.error('Something went wrong.', err);
    });
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <span id="app-root">
        <!-- APP ROOT -->
    </span>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

**template.html**

```html
<template>
    <div class="welcome">
        <h2>Welcome to the Household Budget Calculator</h2>
        <p>We help you divide household expenses fairly.</p>
        <h4>How it works:</h4>
        <ol>
            <li>Enter names</li>
            <li>Fill household expenses</li>
            <li>Each of you fills in their income</li>
            <li>Hit Calculate</li>
            <li>Enjoy a blissful partnership!</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="button-area">
            <button onclick="next()">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```